# Upate userform combobox when rights to sourceworkbook are available

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform with a combobox in it. This combobox is filled with a list from another Workbook.

Some users that need to use my userform do not have the rights to open my combobox source workbook.

What I want to do is rebuild my code so that it updates the combobox whenever someone with the right rights uses the userform.

When someone without the rights uses it it should "skip" the upating of the combobox and work with the last updated version.

this is my code now, any ideas how I should change it to fulfill my needs.

```
Dim ListItems As Variant, i As Integer
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
    With Me.cmbOperators
    .Clear ' remove existing entries from the listbox
    ' turn screen updating off,
    ' prevent the user from seeing the source workbook being opened
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' open the source workbook as ReadOnly
    Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open("path", _
        False, True)
    ListItems = SourceWB.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B121").Value
    ' get the values you want
    SourceWB.Close False ' close the source workbook without saving changes
    Set SourceWB = Nothing
    ListItems = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ListItems)
    ' convert values to a vertical array
    For i = 1 To UBound(ListItems)
        .AddItem ListItems(i) ' populate the listbox
    Next i
    .ListIndex = -1 ' no items selected, set to 0 to select the first item
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

I have no rights to this file myself so can't test it now, can the following work?

at the beginning

```
 On error goto errorhandler
```

at the end

```
errorhandler:
check=0
resume next
```

my changed code:

```
Dim ListItems As Variant, i As Integer
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
With Me.cmbOperators
check = 1
    '.Clear ' remove existing entries from the listbox
    ' turn screen updating off,
    ' prevent the user from seeing the source workbook being opened
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' open the source workbook as ReadOnly
    Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open("\\rsdfp1\mteam\Bestanden SVs\Employees overview\Masterfile Employees Production.xlsx", _
        False, True)
    If check = 1 Then .Clear
    ListItems = SourceWB.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B121").Value
    ' get the values you want
    SourceWB.Close False ' close the source workbook without saving changes
    Set SourceWB = Nothing
    ListItems = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ListItems)
    ' convert values to a vertical array
    For i = 1 To UBound(ListItems)
        .AddItem ListItems(i) ' populate the listbox
    Next i
    .ListIndex = -1 ' no items selected, set to 0 to select the first item
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

Comment: You'll need to use error handling. I don't have the error code in mind for missing rights, but you should find it easily (testing on one of the computers that don't have access to the source workbook!)

Comment: I've tried to rebuild it so that it only clears and tries to fill the box when the sourcefile can be opened. Tried using debug.print but don't have the skills to made it work

Comment: What do you mean "the last updated version"?  If you mean the version in the memory of someone else's computer when they ran it and successfully accessed the source file, you can't do that without copying the list to somewhere that the new user will be able to access (e.g. in the workbook instead of in the source file).  If you mean the version of the list as it existed in your code the last time you updated the code, that will work - it will just require the inclusion of some error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For error handling in this case, you can use a simple `On Error Resume Next`, and then test whether `SourceWB` has been opened.

```
Dim ListItems As Variant, i As Integer
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
    With Me.cmbOperators
        ' turn screen updating off,
        ' prevent the user from seeing the source workbook being opened
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ' open the source workbook as ReadOnly
        On Error Resume Next
        Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open("path", _
                                      False, True)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not SourceWB Is Nothing Then
            .Clear ' remove existing entries from the listbox
            ListItems = SourceWB.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B121").Value
            ' get the values you want
            SourceWB.Close False ' close the source workbook without saving changes
            Set SourceWB = Nothing
            ListItems = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ListItems)
            ' convert values to a vertical array
            For i = 1 To UBound(ListItems)
                .AddItem ListItems(i) ' populate the listbox
            Next i
        End If
        .ListIndex = -1 ' no items selected, set to 0 to select the first item
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
```

However, this will leave the user with the list as it existed in your original code - it will **not** give the list as it was the last time someone successfully accessed the source file.

Comment: If I'd remove .clear and added me.cmboperators.clear in the if not, wouldn't then be the list like the last updated version?

Comment: My apologies - I should have moved that `.Clear` inside the `If`.  When someone runs the macro and they don't have access to the "source" file, the list that they will see will be whatever you hardcoded the list to be when you last saved the code.  It will not be what the previous user (who did have access to the "source" file) saw.  I.e. the previous user is not updating your code, they are just updating the list in their computer's memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use error handling in your case :

I'm just not sure that the error code for not enough right to access a file is 75. But you can change that easily! ;)

```
    Sub test_Mick17()


    Dim ListItems As Variant, i As Integer
    Dim SourceWB As Workbook
    With Me.cmbOperators

        '.Clear ' remove existing entries from the listbox
        ' turn screen updating off,
        ' prevent the user from seeing the source workbook being opened
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False



    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        ' open the source workbook as ReadOnly
        Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open("\\rsdfp1\mteam\Bestanden SVs\Employees overview\Masterfile Employees Production.xlsx", _
        False, True)
        If Check = 1 Then .Clear
        ListItems = SourceWB.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B121").value
        ' get the values you want
        SourceWB.Close False ' close the source workbook without saving changes
        Set SourceWB = Nothing
        ListItems = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ListItems)
        ' convert values to a vertical array
        For i = 1 To UBound(ListItems)
        .AddItem ListItems(i) ' populate the listbox
        Next i


NoRigths:
        .ListIndex = -1 ' no items selected, set to 0 to select the first item
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With


    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 75 Then
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
                Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Resume NoRigths
    End If

    End Sub
```